# How can I add Constraint Layout buttons to another layout Programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to create a list of dynamic constraint layout buttons that are updated every time a user changes the text inside of an Edittext. The text inside the Edit text will be used in an HTTP volley request that will give me information about the text of the button. The reason I am using a constraint layout button instead of a normal button is that I have a lot of information that is configured in a way that using a normal button text wouldn't be possible. I have already compiled a list of Constraint layout buttons all I need to do is add them to the main layout and Constrain. But I have no way to add them to the layout.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=" + searchEditText.getText().toString() + "&limit=10";

                NetworkBridge.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        ArrayList<SearchEntryInfo> searchedItemInfo = new ArrayList<SearchEntryInfo>();

                        ArrayList<ConstraintLayout> buttons = new ArrayList<ConstraintLayout>();

                        //float[] test = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                searchedItemInfo.add(new SearchEntryInfo(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("symbol"), response.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"), response.getJSONObject(i).getString("currency"), response.getJSONObject(i).getString("stockExchange"), response.getJSONObject(i).getString("exchangeShortName")));
                            }

                            for(int i = 0; i < searchedItemInfo.size(); i++)
                            {
                                ConstraintLayout currentBtn = new ConstraintLayout(getBaseContext());
                                ConstraintSet currentBtnConsts = new ConstraintSet();

                                currentBtn.setId(View.generateViewId());

                                currentBtn.setMaxHeight(55);
                                currentBtn.setMinWidth(380);

                                TextView currentSym = new TextView(getBaseContext());

                                currentSym.setText(searchedItemInfo.get(i).getSymbol());
                                currentSym.setTextSize(20);
                                currentSym.setHeight(25);
                                currentSym.setWidth(85); //In Sp make use DP's eventually
                                currentSym.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                currentSym.setTypeface(font);
                                currentSym.setId(View.generateViewId());

                                TextView currentName = new TextView(getBaseContext());

                                currentName.setText(searchedItemInfo.get(i).getName());
                                currentName.setTextSize(14);
                                currentName.setHeight(19);
                                currentName.setWidth(250);
                                currentName.setTextColor(0xE6E1E1);
                                currentName.setTypeface(font);
                                currentName.setId(View.generateViewId());

                                currentBtn.addView(currentSym);
                                currentBtn.addView(currentName);

                                //currentBtnConsts.clone(searchLayout);

                                currentBtnConsts.connect(currentSym.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 16);
                                currentBtnConsts.connect(currentSym.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 4);

                                currentBtnConsts.connect(currentName.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 16);
                                currentBtnConsts.connect(currentSym.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, currentSym.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 2);
                                currentBtnConsts.connect(currentSym.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);

                                currentBtnConsts.applyTo(currentBtn);

                                buttons.add(currentBtn);
                            }


                            /*int[] constButtonIds = new int[buttons.size()];

                            for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
                            {
                                constButtonIds[i] = buttons.get(i).getId();
                            }*/


                            ConstraintSet constMainSearchLayout = new ConstraintSet();

                            constMainSearchLayout.clone(searchLayout);

                            //constMainSearchLayout.createVerticalChain(constButtonIds[0], ConstraintSet.TOP, constButtonIds[constButtonIds.length -1],  ConstraintSet.BOTTOM , constButtonIds, test, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD);

                            constMainSearchLayout.applyTo(searchLayout);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error
                    }
                }));
            }
```

Here is what it should look like except with many of the same things that change dynamically based on what the response gives me.
[image]

Comment: what do you means by a constrainlayout button, i can't visualize what your layout should look like

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I made some changes to the question.